# Extract data form linkedin connection object in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I am using [linkedIn](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) gem.

https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

Here is the code I am getting linkedin connections

```
  @linkedin.authorize_from_access(auth_provider.token, auth_provider.secret)
  @connections = @linkedin.connections
```

I am getting connection as xml format. Here is the connection obj data

```
<%= debug connection%>
```

> name="document"
>   children=[#,
>
> children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="first-name"
>   children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="last-name"
>   children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="headline"
>   children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="location"
>   children=[#,
>
> children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="country"
>   children=[#,
>
> children=[#]>,
>
> ]>, #
>
> "\n ">]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="industry"
>   children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="api-standard-profile-request"
>   children=[#,
>
> children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="headers"
>   attributes=[#]
>   children=[#,
>
> children=[#,
>
> children=[#]>,
>
> , #
>
> name="value"
>   children=[#]>,
>
> ]>, #
>
> "\n ">]>,
>
> ]>, #
>
> "\n ">,
>
> children=[#,
>
> children=[#]>,
>
> ]>, #
>
> "\n ">]>]>>

How can I extract the data from this object to get connection name and their details?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a perfect fit for Nokogiri:

http://nokogiri.org/

```
connection.xpath("//document").each do |document|
  first_name = document.xpath("/first-name").content
  ...
end
```

Here's an explanation of [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) that should help.